# Layer visibility

Tags: qgis, layers

I am using QGIS version 3.20.3 and I have a problem. About a project I have received some file forms but one of them is empty (zero elements). I report this problem to the producer of these files and they reply that, for them, the problem does not exist and that they are able to view all the elements of the layer. How can I go about viewing the items?

[image]

Comment: If they are shapefiles, are all files present, minimum *.shp, *.shx, *.dbf for each layer? Many (at least people sending me files) are only sending the *.shp file

Comment: You should provide more details, otherwise its difficult to help (just guesswork). Can you share the "empty" file? What kind of filetype is it?